# Open-Source or Free ESB what Runs on IIS

Tags: .net, iis, esb

I'm looking for a ESB Open-Source Solution for a project I'm working for. Unfortunately All of the ESB that I've found are for Linux or they run in IIS but I must pay for a license.

Please If you know what Open-Source ESB runs on IIS tell me.

Answer (score 0):

ESB as in Enterprise Service Bus? In that case, [NServiceBus](http://nservicebus.com/), by far. They have both a free Open Source version and a commercial Enterprise version.

Comment: It seems the free version of NServiceBus is no longer available.